# Launch Clojure REPL from java swing

Tags: java, programming-languages, clojure

[image: Java Swing REPL]

How to Launch REPL using java Swing application. As shown in Image. This REPL should be able to run all functions provided by Clojure Build-in libraray and other developed libraries by user. (provied as jar in classpath). 
Point is, how to run **Java clojure.jar clojure.main** from swing so that it will show user defined Namespace. like **myRepl=>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly. Do you  want to write such REPL or to just use it?

In any case, googling for "clojure swing repl" seems to show interesting results, one of which is: https://github.com/alandipert/clj-swingrepl

N.B. I haven't tested this.

Comment: I just want to use it. not Build. So how do we call REPL from Swing application?

Comment: Have you followed the link above?

Comment: This thing makes new REPL. My Question is, without making new REPL, can we call existing REPL through some java app.

Comment: @vikbehal that's not what your question asks - in your example you explicitly create a new REPL.

Comment: @AdrianMouat This is just to demonstrate!